# What holder for a 3,6x10mm fuse?

Tags: fuses, fuse-holders

How would one mount a fuse that is 3,6mm in diameter and 10mm in length  on a  PCB?  I can't seem to find a method to do this, browsing through the electronic components suppliers.

Datasheet: http://datasheet.octopart.com/MCPDS-004-Multicomp-datasheet-10027002.pdf

Comment: This appears to be a shopping question. However, it may be useful to answer. It does not need a fuse holder. The fuse can be held by two individual clips in a PCB, e.g. [Fuse Clips](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/fuses-sockets-circuit-breakers/fuse-holders/fuse-clips/)

On a page that lists that type of fuse Farnell have a link to their [catalogue](http://www.easyflip.co.uk/Farnell_element14_2013_UK/book.html?page=2415). That shows a PCB mount fuse holder in the right-most column. Unfortunately, the part number is wrong!
Email Farnell sales and ask for the correct part number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you would use individual clips mounted in a pcb. http://bentronics.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=16_85_87_132_788&products_id=4065
[image]